# Last 30 days formula in process builder not working

Tags: process-builder, tasks

Creating a PB that will update a checkbox on the Lead to True if,
1) Status = Completed (this is done)
2) Due Date is within the last 30 days.

When I try to create a formula for that and use LAST 30 DAYS in the PB it doesn't work, I get an error: "The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Found 'LAST'".

How do I create this PB so that it can check to see if there is a task that has been completed in the last 30 days (using the due date, not last modified date or created date)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the built-in [DateTime function](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) TODAY(), and then simply subtract 30 from it. Thus your formula for the Due Date field would be DueDate >= the following:

```
TODAY() - 30
```

Comment: That's not working. I have Due Date formula equals TODAY() - 30.

Comment: Also, will that prevent it from being marked as true if it's 45 days in the past? I need it within a range of the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do relative date functions like "LAST 30 DAYS" but you can do math on the field somenthing like that

```
TODAY() - 30
```

Comment: So I won't be able to get a date range like last 30 days? My concern is that if there is a task from 300 days ago it will also mark as true since it technically meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got folks.

AND(
ActivityDate >= Today() - 30,
ActivityDate < Today()+ 1
)

Makes sure it isn't greater than 30 days ago and because you can put the due date in the future, it doesn't mark as TRUE if it's greater than today.